# Minimum version of Git to support Git Submodules

Tags: git

What is the minimum version of git required to support git sub modules ? I am searching it but cant find it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Submodule support has been available in Git since version 1.5.3.

See https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial.